# How would you define a recursive set for Lists of numbers in math

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In computer science we often work with nested data structures. An example is a lists of lists.

```
[1, 2, 3]

[1, 2, [1, 2, [1, [0, 4], 3]]]
```

It caught me by surprise, but I can't find a logical counterpart using *correct* set notation. In programming languages if you consider a type (i.e. class) to represent a set, it's a natural thing to allow recursion, but I wonder how this can be expressed in math.

I know that I can use a graph G to encode the relations between all elements, but it's awkward in this case, because each vertex here would a unique thing. The number `1` is referred to many times in this graph, but always at different position, so the set of vertices indeed needs to treat every `1` as a different vertex

The closest thing I can come up with is the following.

let $ V $ be a non empty set, define

$R := \{(x_1,...,x_n) |x_i \in  V \lor x_i \in R, n \in \mathbb{N} \}$

So, the question is: Is this definition of a *recursive set* legitimate, or how would you fix it? My gut feeling tells me that defining a set using itself does not make sense in math.

Comment: Even in programming you cannot have a list with infinite level of recursion. You need to define separately lists of depth $k$ (or, in the mathematical formulation, sequences), whose elements can belong to the previously defined depth types.

Comment: so, you mean a proper solution would be to define a sequence of sets like so:  $R_k := \{(x_1,...,x_n) |x_i \in  V \lor x_i \in R_{k-1}, n \in \mathbb{N} \}$, then $R=\bigcup R_k$ ?

Comment: Well it is closer to what happens with lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many misconceptions here. Let me start with the biggest one:

- Computer science is distinct from mathematics

Actually, up until the actual physical hardware gets involved, computer science is an offshoot of mathematics, and still fits neatly within it. Those great names in the birth of computer science, such as Turing and Von Neumann? Those were mathematicians, and what they were doing was - and still is - mathematics. Many significant names currently working in each of the fields also regularly contribute directly to the other, and in fact most of their work is still common to both fields.

Types, recursion, languages, tokenization, regular expressions, algorithms, etc. - these are all mathematical concepts, many of which predate the invention of the computer (even the name "computer" predates that, as it used to refer to a person). The only reason you mostly talk about them in computer science is because that is the specialization within mathematics to which they most pertain. But just like since Riemann, modern Number Theory is rife with the tools of analysis: integration, derivatives, power series, etc., so too does computer science have a rich interplay with other branches of mathematics.

So the idea that the subjects you are discussing cannot be adequately expressed in mathematics is wrong. They are mathematics.

- Set theory cannot handle nesting and recursion.

Set theories (there are a variety of them, with differences in construction and axioms) commonly do not even allow for the existence of objects that are not sets. Even when they do, we call such non-sets "ur-elements", and mostly do not discuss them. So if sets are not sets of ur-elements, what are they sets of? Other sets! We have one set that contains nothing, $\varnothing = \{\}$, then we have the set that just contains it: $\{\varnothing\}$, and the set that contains both: $\{\varnothing, \{\varnothing\}\}$, and so on. These sets are *all* recursive, building on earlier sets. Unlike in computer science, we can make sets that are infinitely wide: $\{\varnothing, \{\varnothing\}, \{\{\varnothing\}\}, \dots \}$.

So sets are recursively defined by their very nature. But even though sets can be infinitely wide, they can only ever be finitely deep, in the sense that if you take a set $S_1$, and then an element of it, $S_2 \in S_1$, and an element of that, $S_3 \in S_2$, and so on, you can only ever do this a finite number of times. Eventually, you will be forced to pick $\varnothing$ as your next element, and the process must stop. This is called "well-foundedness" and is usually a consequence of the axiom of regularity. So is this weaker than the recursion you talk about? No. You haven't examined the recursion in computer science close enough. It also has a finite depth that cannot be surpassed. In some sense, this is obvious, because computer science is limited to the finite by the nature of its subject matter. But it is also carefully baked into the definitions, if you examine them in detail.

- Lists, Arrays, Types should be modeled as sets.

Lists and arrays are not sets, but finite sequences. Their elements have an order, which the elements of sets do not have, and they can contain the same element more than once, of which sets are not capable. The analogous object in general mathematics is the sequence $a_0, a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n$, which is effectively identical to an "array", and Lists are just arrays with added rules for handling.

Probably the closest analogy to a Type outside of computer science is not a set, but a [Category](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_theory). The full resemblance may be hard to spot from the definition of a category because the language is different. But what determines the nature of any conceptual class in mathematics is how you handle them, and in Categories, this is done by defining its "morphisms", while for Types, it is done by defining properties and methods. But the end result is pretty much the same: a collection of objects which share common attributes that can be applied to all of them, but individually will have differences between themselves.

Comment: thank you for your time to craft this answer. what do you think about the comment I made above. would that represent a set that can model all lists of lists?